# How can I reuse expressions within LINQ statements?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I like to reuse expressions for DRY reasons, but how do I reuse the expressions within a LINQ statement?

e.g.

I have

```
public static class MyExpressions {
    public static Expression<Func<Product,bool>> IsAGoodProduct() {
        return (p) => p.Quality>3;
    }
}
```

And would like to use that in LINQ statements, so

```
  var goodProds = from p in dataContext.Products
                  where ????? // how do I use IsAGoodProduct here?
                  select p;
```

Sure, I could use the IQueryableExtension.Where function, but that would make joins and other functions alot uglier for more complex queries.

Is this possible or is it a limitation of LINQ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you move from the LINQ syntactic sugar it is possible:

```
var goodProds = dataContext.Products.Where(MyExpressions.IsAGoodProduct());
```

Without it, it isn't possible.

There's nothing to stop you mixing the two styles to build a single query though.

Example:

```
  var goodProds = from p in dataContext.Products
                                       .Where(MyExpressions.IsAGoodProduct())
                  group p by p.Category into g 
                  select new {Category = g.Key, ProductCount = g.Group.Count()};
```

Comment: @Gary -- hope you don't mind that I added an example to make it clearer.

Comment: What about using: "where IsAGoodProduct().Compile().Invoke()"

Comment: @Razzie, no that wouldn't work - firstly, it needs an *expression tree* (since it is a data-context) - not a delegate. Second, the invoke simply can't be used like that.

Comment: @Marc ok thanks, I tested it but with a List<T> and it worked there, so I wondered.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and wanted to preserve the ability to use extension methods within the query syntax (as with ordinary supported functions...). A solution might be [this library](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq) (spoiler: I‘m the author).

You just implement the method to reuse twice, once for general use and once for queries.

```
public static class MyFunctions {
    [InjectLambda]
    public static bool IsAGoodProduct(Product product) {
        return product.Quality>3;
    }
    public static Expression<Func<Product,bool>> IsAGoodProduct() {
        return (p) => p.Quality>3;
    }
}
```

The actual query can then look like expected.

```
var goodProds = from p in dataContext.Products.ToInjectable()
                where p.IsAGoodProduct()
                select p;
```

The `ToInjectable` call creates a lightweight proxy, which replaces the `IsAGoodProduct` method call (if marked accordingly) with the desired lambda expression. Thus, you can use extension methods wherever within the query -- parameterized methods work as well.

Comment: Did you create this library? Probably a good idea to state it here.

Comment: My very first sentence should say that: „I [...] wanted to preserve the [...]“. Since english isn’t my native tongue, it may not be as clear as intended. I‘ll edit my post for further clarification.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem. It is not supported out of the box and it is a major problem for LOB applications. I ended up writing a code-project article about LINQ expressions reuse, including a very small utility called LinqExpressionPrjection that enables the reuse in projections (including into anonymous types).

Find the article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=4620566).

You can get the assembly for the projection reuse as a [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/LinqExpressionProjection) and the source is on [CodePlex](http://linqexprprojection.codeplex.com/).

Some time has passed since your post. I hope it is still helpful for you. If not, maybe for others reading this thread.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I've come across this [useful article](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/) which explains how you can create dynamic LINQ Queries that reference functions wrapped as Expressions using a custom ToExpandable() extension method. The solution provided can be used within the various parts of a LINQ Query all while preserving the use of [comprehension syntax](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqsyntax.aspx) instead of resorting to lambda syntax.